# Create data frame with vectors and loops

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

I need to create a dataframe "cis" composed of 75 vectors, like the datframe below but with 75 elements instead of 3 :

```
cis <- data.frame('sub1.ci'=as.vector(cis$mnes_Subject_1$ci[mask]),'sub2.ci'=as.vector(cis$mnes_Subject_2$ci[mask]),'sub3.ci'=as.vector(cis$mnes_Subject_3$ci[mask]))
```

The elements of the dataframe should be on the same format : for k=1 to 75,

```
'subk.ci'=as.vector(cis$mnes_Subject_k$ci[mask]).
```

It seems simple but I can't manage it! I tried with `lapply` but I cannot seem to make it work.

I would use some help here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data frame you're after with

```
cis <- data.frame(lapply(1:75, function(x)cis[[paste0("mnes_Subject_",x)]]$ci[mask]))
```

then set the column names with :

```
names(cis) <- paste0("sub",1:75,".ci")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Why can I skip the "as.vector" function? I thought lapply returned a list and not a vector?

Comment: @Clin From `?data.frame`: If a list or data frame or matrix is passed to data.frame it is as if each component or column had been passed as a separate argument (except for matrices protected by I).